# Bootstrap collapse and id

Tags: php, css

Using php and mysql and bootstrap.
The php and mysql works fine but for the bootstrap, if i am actually calling values from

```
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
```

im getting all rows in a given div but if i want to use bootstrap collapse

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">More info</button>
<div id="demo" class="collapse">
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
</div>
```

Since the id of the div will be the same, only 1 will collapse if theres more than 1 row. Even if i used modal, when clicking on the button to display to modal, only for the first value will display

```
<?php
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){?>

<div class="w3-container w3-card-2 w3-white w3-margin-bottom">
          <div class="w3-container">
          some stuff`
          <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">More info</button>
         <div id="demo" class="collapse">`
             <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
         </div>
        </div>
        </div>
<?php }?>
```

The problem is for the button thanks

Comment: So use different ids.

Comment: how to do that, the php is duplicating the div for every row in the database, so it will duplicated the collapse id 3 times

Comment: Only if you code it that way. So code it to do what is required

Comment: Use a counter or use some data from row.

Comment: Start by showing us the inside of your while loop then somebody might be able to suggest a solution

Comment: i edited the post to display the loop used. I want to know how to loop the id #demo too, thanks

Comment: Seriously, read more about formatting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need unique ids for each row you can do this, for example:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $current_id = 'id-' . $i;
    $i++;?>

<div class="w3-container w3-card-2 w3-white w3-margin-bottom">
    <div class="w3-container">
    some stuff
    <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?=$current_id?>">More info</button>
    <div id="<?=$current_id?>" class="collapse">
        <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php }?>
```

In this case you will have unique ids - `id-0`, `id-1`, `id-2`, etc. assigned to each item of your output.

Comment: Btw sorry to bother you more, if i want to swap the <div id="chart_div"> to be using unique id, then in the script tag for javascript, how will i target it since it will be document.getelementbyid?
thanks for your time

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean. You need to change id? you need to change javascript? Anyway - ask another question with new code snippets.

Comment: If i want to use unique ids for
' <div id="chart_div" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>'
 how i am supposed to target the ids, var chart = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document.getElementById('chart_div');?

Answer (score 0):

Add data to **data-target** button attribute and **id** collapse div attribute to distinct each one.

[JSFidlle based on your div](https://jsfiddle.net/pur182fa/)

```
<div class="w3-container w3-card-2 w3-white w3-margin-bottom">
    <div class="w3-container">
          some stuff`
          <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">More info</button>
         <div id="demo" class="collapse">`
             <div id="chart_div" style="">0</div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="w3-container w3-card-2 w3-white w3-margin-bottom">
    <div class="w3-container">
          some stuff`
          <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo1">More info</button>
         <div id="demo1" class="collapse">`
             <div id="chart_div" style="">1</div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="w3-container w3-card-2 w3-white w3-margin-bottom">
    <div class="w3-container">
          some stuff`
          <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2">More info</button>
         <div id="demo2" class="collapse">`
             <div id="chart_div" style="">2</div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```